# Matlab: computing signal to noise ratio (SNR) of two highly correlated time domain signals

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I'm working in the space of biosignal acquisition. I made a experiment as detailed below, and am now trying to obtain some results from the data.

I have a text file of a signal in Matlab. I loaded the signal onto a waveform generator, then I recorded the generator output on an oscilloscope.
I imported the recorded signal from the oscilloscope back into Matlab. 
The Pearson's correlation coefficient between the original signal and the oscilloscope signal is 0.9958 (obtained using corrcoeff function).

I want to compute the SNR of the oscilloscope signal (what I'm calling my signal plus whatever noise is introduced through the digital-to-analog conversion and visa-versa). I have attached a snippet of the 2 signals for reference.

So my original signal is X and oscilloscope signal is X + N.
I used the snr function to compute SNR as follows.

```
snr(original, (oscilloscope - original))
```

The result I got was 20.44 dB.
This seems off to me as I would have thought with such a high correlation, that the SNR should be much higher?

Or is it not appropriate to try and compute SNR in this sort of situation?

All help is appreciated.

Thanks

[image]

**Edit:** Graph of a couple of results vs Sleutheye's simulated relationship

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be surprised at just how even such moderate SNR can still result in fairly high correlations.

I ran an experiment to illustrate the approximate relation between correlation and signal-to-noise-ratio estimate. Since I did not have your specific EEG signal, I just used a reference constant signal and some white Gaussian noise. Keep in mind that the relationship could be affected by the nature of the signal and noise, but it should give you an idea of what to expect. This simulation can be executed with the following code:

```
SNR = [10:1:40];

M = 10000;
C = zeros(size(SNR));
for i=1:length(SNR)

  x = ones(1,M);
  K = sqrt(sum(x.*x)/M)*power(10, -SNR(i)/20);
  z = x + K*randn(size(x));
  C(i) = xcorr(x,z,0)./sqrt(sum(x.*x)*sum(z.*z));
end

figure(1);
hold off; plot(SNR, C);
corr0 = 0.9958;
hold on;  plot([SNR(1) SNR(end)], [corr0 corr0], 'k:');
snr0 = 20.44;
hold on;  plot([snr0 snr0], [min(C) max(C)], 'r:');

xlabel('SNR (dB)');
ylabel('Correlation');
```

The dotted black horizontal line highlights your 0.9958 correlation measurement, and the dotted red vertical line highlights your 20.44 dB SNR result.

[image]

I'd say that's a pretty good match!

In fact, for this specific case in my simulation (`x = 1`; `z = x + N(0,σ)`) if we denote `C(x,z)` to be the correlation between `x` and `z`, and `σ` as the noise standard deviation, we can actually show that:

[image]

Given a correlation value of 0.9958, this would yield an SNR of 20.79dB, which is consistent with your results.

Comment: That's a great answer, thanks. 
I obtained my correlation value using `corrcoef` instead of `xcorr`.
Am I right in thinking though that using `xcorr` in the manner 

`C(i) = xcorr(x,z,0)./sqrt(sum(x.*x)*sum(z.*z));` 

is essentially the same as you're  computing: 

`covariance(x,z) / sqrt ( variance(x)*variance(z) )` 

which always gives a value between +/-1, which is the same as Pearson's?

Also, I don't fully understand your final case. 
I haven't seen the formula (correlation^2/(1-correlation^2)) = noise standard deviation before?

Thanks again

Comment: Also, a more trivial question, but why is there a minus in your dB/magnitude calculations, both in the matlab code (`-SNR(i)`) and the last case (which relates back to the last part of my previous comment).

Comment: 1) wrt `corrcoef` vs `xcorr`: they are not equivalent. `xcorr(x,z,0)` computes `sum(x.*z)` which is not the same as `cov(x,z) = sum((x-mean(x)).*(z-mean(z))`. Also, Pearson's correlation isn't defined 
2) The formula is specific to the signal involved here. There is some derivation involved (eg. E{sum(x.*x)} = M, E{sum(z.*z)} = M(1+σ^2), ...)
3) The code uses a negative sign (for dB/mag) because it computes the magnitude of the noise relative to a signal of unitary magnitude. If I had used a noise with unitary magnitude and scaled the signal instead it would have be a positive sign.

Comment: I ran your code, except changed x to a 10Hz sin wave (with an amplitude offset) and computed correlation using xcorr and corrcoef. As you said, xcorr and corrcoef are not the same (unless I remove the amplitude offset). For a correlation of 0.9958, the Pearson's method (corrcoef) gives an SNR of 24dB and cross correlation method (xcorr) gives 19dB. 
In the case relating to my EEG signal, the EEG is filtered between 0.5-100 Hz, so the mean (DC offset) is removed anyway. So both corrcoef and xcorr give me the same result (xcorr = 0.9955 and corrcoef = 0.9958).

Comment: I then tried putting my EEG signal as x in your above code. The corresponding SNR for a correlation of 0.9958 is 40 dB according to the graph. Which value is correct? 19 dB, 20.4 dB, 24 dB, 40 dB?

Comment: The formula for `K` was simplified for the specific case where `x` has unitary power. Putting a sine wave & your EEG signal that did not have unitary power was thus giving incorrect results. I've updated the formula to be more general, and it should now give results that are closer even for different signals.

Comment: Have a look at my edit which includes a more results. The results fall off slightly at lower SNRs. The correlation coefficient is independent of scaling but SNR isn't, so I used the following method to make sure the Oscilloscope signal is scaled to the same amplitude as the Original. `OscScaled = ((Osc - mean(Osc))/std(Osc))*std(Original) + mean(Original)`. Using this method I got the results in the edit labeled _"Results - Scaling"_ in the legend. If I just subtract the mean from the Osc channel, I get even closer to the theoretical model, in the graph they're labeled _"Results - Mean"_.